# Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php

Tags: php, git, heroku, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my php app from github to heroku, but it's not working. I've had experience with deploying php apps to heroku, but for some reason, I'm having trouble this time.

This is what I've done.

1. Created an app in heroku
2. Linked my github to my heroku app
3. Added a remote to heroku app from my local directory
4. Set buildpack to php
5. Run `git push heroku master`

My directory has the following files:

```
home.html
index.php
index.css
```

Here's my `index.php`: `Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php`

This is what i got after step 5:

```
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
Writing objects: 100% (52/52), 1.12 MiB | 1.23 MiB/s, done.
Total 52 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/php
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to appp.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/appp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/appp.git'
```

Here is my `heroku logs`:

```
2015-11-19T00:22:31.307947+00:00 heroku[api]: Set BUILDPACK_URL config vars by email@gmail.com
2015-11-19T00:22:31.307947+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by email@gmail.com
2015-11-19T00:22:43.284779+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-19T00:22:43.284789+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php
2015-11-19T00:22:43.284790+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
2015-11-19T00:27:00.648462+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Procfile` by email@gmail.com
2015-11-19T00:27:01.379352+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: Awaiting client
2015-11-19T00:27:01.441226+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Procfile`
2015-11-19T00:27:01.858759+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-19T00:27:03.971434+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-19T00:27:03.989162+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: State changed from up to complete
2015-11-19T00:30:14.310979+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-19T00:30:14.310987+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php
2015-11-19T00:30:14.310988+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
2015-11-19T00:31:54.735764+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-19T00:31:54.735775+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php
2015-11-19T00:31:54.735776+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
2015-11-19T00:34:31.326372+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-19T00:34:31.326383+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php
2015-11-19T00:34:31.326385+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
2015-11-19T00:34:37.003934+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-19T00:34:37.003944+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php
2015-11-19T00:34:37.003946+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. In my git repo, I had a separate folder that had all the html and php files that would display the website. Once I moved them out to the main directory, heroku was able to detect that it's a php app.

Comment: would you please elaborate and be specific about what was the new folder structure after the fix?  I would help

Comment: from what I understood, your app should have the index.php file and Procfile in the same folder. That folder is considered the root by Heroku

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I needed to have a **composer.json** file in the same directory where my git folder is. Also make sure you included the json file in your commit before trying to do *git push heroku master*.

My composer.json file contains only this so it's a valid json.

> { }

Comment: What if I don't have composer.json ? Do I need to create one ? My app is very simple, just 1 index.html and 1 css file ...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you do the following things.

- Create a index.html with some test data.
- Create `composer.json` that has only `{}` in the file
- Create `index.php` that has `<?php include_once("index.html"); ?>`
- Now commit these and push using this command `git push heroku master`

all the files should be in same directory.