# Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz

Tags: heroku

## Goal

I'm very new to Heroku, and I'm trying to deploy a **very simple site** into Heroku.

**Site Structure**

[image]

As you can see, I'm not trying to deploy a complex Node.js or Laravel Site here.

---

## Steps

I log-in to heroku of course, then

```
cd idesign4u/
git init
heroku git:remote -a idesign4u
git add .
git commit -am "Project Initialization"
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
```

I got this

```
Buildpack set. Next release on idesign4u will use heroku/php.
Run git push heroku master to create a new release using this buildpack.
```

I thought I am all set. Then I ran

```
git push heroku master
```

---

## Result

I kept getting

```
Counting objects: 67, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
Writing objects: 100% (67/67), 60.75 MiB | 6.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 67 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to idesign4u.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/idesign4u.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/idesign4u.git'
```

> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz

---

## Questions

How do I bypass that?

Are there any other settings that I need to do in the Heroku site?

---

## Note

I found some SO post like this one here:

[Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793325/push-rejected-failed-to-detect-set-buildpack-heroku-php)

I took a look at it, but it is not really relevant in my case here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to deploy a static website to Heroku but specifying the `heroku/php` builpack which expects, well… a PHP app.

Two possible ways of doing this:

**Meet the [requirements](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) of the `heroku/php` webpack**:

1. Have some PHP code.  For example, an `index.php` file with a redirect, like:

   `<?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ) ;  ?>`
2. Have a `composer.json` file, which can just be:

   `{}`

**Use [`heroku-buildpack-static`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static)**:

This is a custom webpack for serving static sites.  A complete guide is available [here](https://gist.github.com/hone/24b06869b4c1eca701f9), but the highlights are:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-static
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/hone/heroku-buildpack-static
heroku static:init
heroku static:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you may want to use some PHP in the future…

1. Change your `index.html` file to `index.php`
2. Commit your changes to master.
3. `git push heroku master`